# Limit on IBM Cloud Object Storage public bucket access

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a public bucket in IBM COS, my questions are:

1. Can we put the limit on the number of calls to the COS public bucket to avoid the DOS attack and is it required?
2. Does IBM COS service handle it itself?

Answer (score 0):

No - it isn't possible to set a request limit or quota.  But the endpoint that the request is sent to is actually a set of load balancers in front of the COS system itself, and should throttle traffic appropriately.  This would be a useful clarification to add to the documentation.